# Interactive Marker: Click directly on sphere or box

Tags: ros, rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm publishing some interactive markers to be able to select different objects from a scene in rviz (see screenshot below. I'm using an **InteractiveMarkerControl.MENU** type.

[image: Interactive Marker]

I'm now able to select the marker, but only by clicking on the "CLICK" text, which is the description of the InteractiveMarkerControl() associated.

Is it possible to have a marker which react **when we click directly on the sphere**?

Thanks in advance.

Ugo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11929/interactive-marker:-click-directly-on-sphere-or-box/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, in fact you are very close already.  Simply set **interaction_mode = InteractiveMarkerControl.BUTTON** in the control which has the sphere shape, then in your feedback message, look for **event_type == InteractiveMarkerFeedback::BUTTON_CLICK**.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-11-21**:
thanks for that